# Tracking when and which links are opened through my app

Tags: android, url, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

We have a social media kind of app where you can post content like messages, links, images etc. We would like to track when a link is pressed in the app, and which urls are opened through the app. The urls are detected in the textviews with the autolink "web" property. Is this possible to achieve with google/firebase analytics or similar?

Comment: Improve your response!
Could you give examples with a description of the codes, for your answer?

This practice will considerably improve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

although your question may not meet community standards.
I will try to answer, from my understanding ...

I believe that you are looking for URL tracking, this practice can be applied to applications and websites.
The most common method used today is:

### Bit.ly

This tool, in addition to URL shortening. It can serve as an effective means of tracking and measuring.
but this tool also has its limitations. You have to study.

### Google Analytics

With this tool you can create and use the Google Analytics tag.
So, follow this event.

It is understood that any url can be tracked with the created tag.
This practice becomes one of the most complex in metrics.

If you need to deepen your question further, be sure to comment.

### Capture outbound links

Find out when users click a link to leave your site.
Note: This article applies only to sites tagged with the analytics.js snippet. (It does not apply to sites tagged with gtag.js.)

You can use Analytics Events to capture clicks on links that take users to a website other than your own.

**Google Tag Manager**

If you use Google Tag Manager to manage your Analytics installation, follow the instructions in Analytics Events to implement events.

Add the tag directly to your site
If you have added the Analytics tag directly to your site, you can copy and paste the script below into your own pages to set up Event measurement for outbound links. You should add this script in your page header, but not within the basic Analytics tag.

If you copy and paste this script exactly as it appears here, your outbound clicks will appear in your Analytics Events reports with a Category of "outbound" and an Action of "click". (In the snippet, these are shown in bold.) You can use these values, or change them and define your own values. Learn more about Event components.

This example assumes that you are using the analytics.js tag. See if you are using Classic Analytics (ga.js) or Universal Analytics (analytics.js).

```js
<script>
/**
* Function that captures a click on an outbound link in Analytics.
* This function takes a valid URL string as an argument, and uses that URL string
* as the event label. Setting the transport method to 'beacon' lets the hit be sent
* using 'navigator.sendBeacon' in browser that support it.
*/
var captureOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
</script>
```

You'll also need to add (or modify) the onclick attribute to your links. Use this example as a model for your own links:

```js
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="captureOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Check out example.com</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it was very helpful. sry for not providing code example.